# WhatsApp notification how to get number sender?

Tags: android, notifications, whatsapp

I have a notification listening service. Earlier, when receiving a notification from WhatsApp, the sender number was received using StatusBarNotification.key. Now it doesn’t work out that way.

I tried to do so and find the number there but it didn’t work out.

```
val bundle = statusbarnotification.notification.extras
if (bundle != null) {
  for (key in bundle!!.keySet()) {
    val value = bundle!!.get(key)
    keyMtb?.add(key)
    if (!(value == null)) {
        mtbValue?.add(value.toString())
    }
   }
}
```

I expected to receive:

```
0|com.whatsapp|1|xxxxxxxxxx@s.whatsapp.net|10043
```

But received:

```
0|com.whatsapp|1|3xxxxxxxxxxxxxOznSkrsd=\n|10043
```